# gcc 6.1 executable file link error

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, gcc

I recently bootstrapped gcc 6.1 to my ubuntu based linux distribution. 
Seemingly it installed properly because I can compile programs written in C and C++. 
I can also run the compiled executables.
I can also compile a program that includes C++11 and C++14 features without any errors but when I try to run these executable I get the following error;

```
./exec: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.21' not found (required by ./ardi)
```

when I run;

```
strings /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 | grep GLIB
```

the list does not include the needed file.
Does it mean gcc 6.1 has those files somewhere else.
How can I locate needed files and redirect gcc. I am new to linux system and not even sure I understand the error correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is because your host libstdc++ library is older than one from your new g++. So you can try to use static linking to avoid external dependency from newer std lib version using `-static-libstdc++` g++ flag. The cost of this solution is increased size of resulting executables.

Comment: if i compile this way the executable runs but the size of the file increased from 200kb to 8mb. is this 8mb standard increase per file or connected to according to some ratio. And how does this affect compile time in general.

Comment: @fredric, Size increased exactly by size of standard library which attached to executable in this case. It is constant size addtion to every executable you will build. Compile time must not change, linking time slightly incresed per executable as well.